# Calibrating an AD592 temperature transducer

Tags: temperature, calibration

This transducer outputs 1uA/K. To convert it to a voltage I've put it in series with a 1k 5% resistor and a 220R trimmer to adjust for the 5% variance, tested with the multimeter to make sure I'm getting exactly 1k, then take the reading from between the transducer and the resistors (I should be getting 1mV/K). I'm using 3.3v from my arduino. I've got the thing set up in my computer room and I wrote a little C# program to get the reading from the arduino over serial and do the calculations to display °C and °F. It does respond to temperature changes. For example, I touched an ice cube to it and the temperature dropped, and I held my lighter next to it and it went up, but it settles in at exactly 68.2°F and doesn't change when there's nothing around it. First off, I think my room feels warmer than 68.2° F, and secondly I'm finding it hard to believe that the temperature in this room is so perfectly stable. I'm wondering how I might go about calibrating the thing.

The datasheet says that it has a range from -25° C to 105° C (248.15 K to 378.15 K). Since water, while liquid, can't be below 0° C and above 100° C (under normal conditions), would it work to wrap the transducer in heat shrink and dunk it in ice/boiling water for a minute or so to test that it's reading 0/100°C? I don't want to damage the transducer, or short it/the arduino out in water, so I'm asking. If I can calibrate those two temperatures I can determine the swing between them to figure out an ideal reading for ambient room temperature, right?

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for AD592 recommends 4-30V supply voltage. 3.3V is probably too low a voltage for AD592 to operate properly. It is more like 3.0V if you take into account 0.3V voltage drop on the resistor ( at room temperature ). Unless you require better than 0.5 C accuracy the calibration is not needed at all.

Comment: I was originally using the 5V pin on the Arduino, but the code that I had already written in C# was written for 3.3V and I didn't want to change it. I'm taking the measurement between the AD592 and the resistor and getting ~.3V. I dunked it in ice water (iced water I poured in a frozen glass, no actual ice cubes) and it went down to -2°C, so I adjusted the trimmer to make it as close to 0 as I could then removed it from the ice water and let it normalize and it still read 68.2°F, so I guess that's actually what it is.

Comment: I think the sensor's supply voltage will make no difference for the code - give it a try.

Comment: It does my code. I wrote it years ago before I really knew "good programming practices" and hard-coded in the math, relying on the measurements being taken with a 3.3v reference. The arduino takes 400 measurements over half a second from the transducer, adding them all up, then sends that value over serial to the C# program, which then divides by 400 to get an average and multiplies by 3.22 to get millivolts (3.3/1024). If I used 5v it would need to multiply it by (5/1024) = 4.88. I know, I'm lazy, but it works with minimal effort rewriting my lazy code.

Comment: @HaLo2FrEeEk You're using Arduino A-to-D to input sense voltage from that 1k resistor? With a 3v reference supply? That gives you about 3mV resolution corresponding to 3 degrees C. No wonder your room temperature seems constant !